# Which polymers are used to make polymer concrete?

Tags: civil-engineering

I was going through the wikipedia page on polymer concretes. It seems like a good type of building material. I was wondering which types of polymers are used in the concrete, since I cannot find any online besides epoxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many categories of binders and more are being added due to research and development in high strength binders. The two categories of binders or resins are thermosetting and thermoplastic. Each has sub categories as shown below.

Thermosetting resins:

- Epoxy
- Polyester
- Acetone formaldehyde
- Phenol formaldehyde

Thermoplastic resins

- Methyl methacrylate
- Indencumaron

[Google book research, click here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=NiQtAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA3&ots=BLCaU29OOc&dq=Indencumaron&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=Indencumaron&f=false)

Comment: Don't know if it can be strictly classified as a 'polymer', but latex is one of the earliest polymer modifiers used in concrete too.